# Run an exe file on a Mac with Wineskin (VseeFace Application)

Tags: macos, exe, wine

I really hope that someone could help me out with my problem.

I want to start an exe File (VSeeFace - see https://www.vseeface.icu for more information) on my Mac with wineskin. VseeFace is an application for Vtubing.

The application starts normally via Wineskin, but as soon as I try to open my avatar (a .vrm file), the software stops and I don't know why. I have searched everywhere and found nothing about my problem, but perhaps that is also due to my limited knowledge of development skills.

Can anyone help me please?

```
My Mac:
MacOS Monterey Version 12.4
Radeon Pro 575X 4 GB

My Wineskin Setup:
Wrapper Version Wineskin 2.9.1.5
Engine WS11WineCX64Bit22.0.1-1
Config Utility - Windows-Version 8
```

VseeFace Software – https://www.vseeface.icu/#download
They also describe how it will work on Linux or maybe Mac,
https://www.vseeface.icu/#running-on-linux-and-maybe-mac

For the Facetracking I run OpenSeeFace (but that seemed to work, I could see the green light of the iMac camera, but I couldn't test it because of my software problem).

I mean I could run the application but on the most important Screen it stops working.

**In the debug.log file I noticed the following messages:**

```
0024:err:shell:HCR_GetFolderAttributes should be called for simple PIDL's only!
0024:fixme:exec:SHELL_execute flags ignored: 0x0000000c

0118:err:module:import_dll Library dsound.dll (which is needed by L"C:\\windows\\system32\\devenum.dll") not found
0118:trace:loaddll:build_module Loaded L"C:\\windows\\system32\\msdmo.dll" at 000000034ABC0000: builtin
0118:err:ole:apartment_add_dll couldn't load in-process dll L"C:\\windows\\system32\\devenum.dll"
0118:err:ole:com_get_class_object no class object {62be5d10-60eb-11d0-bd3b-00a0c911ce86} could be created for context 0x1
0118:err:module:import_dll Library dsound.dll (which is needed by L"C:\\windows\\system32\\devenum.dll") not found
0118:err:ole:apartment_add_dll couldn't load in-process dll L"C:\\windows\\system32\\devenum.dll"
0118:err:ole:com_get_class_object no class object {62be5d10-60eb-11d0-bd3b-00a0c911ce86} could be created for context 0x1
0118:err:ole:apartment_add_dll couldn't find function DllGetClassObject in L"C:\\windows\\system32\\devenum.dll"
0118:err:ole:com_get_class_object no class object {62be5d10-60eb-11d0-bd3b-00a0c911ce86} could be created for context 0x1

0118:err:ole:com_get_class_object no class object {62be5d10-60eb-11d0-bd3b-00a0c911ce86} could be created for context 0x1
0118:trace:loaddll:build_module Loaded L"C:\\windows\\system32\\Avrt.dll" at 00000002F2930000: builtin
0118:trace:loaddll:build_module Loaded L"C:\\VSeeFace\\VSeeFace_Data\\Plugins\\x86_64\\LeapCV4.dll" at 000000010A220000: native
0118:trace:loaddll:build_module Loaded L"C:\\windows\\system32\\VCRUNTIME140_1.dll" at 00000002F7F20000: builtin
0118:err:module:import_dll Loading library MSVCP140_2.dll (which is needed by L"C:\\VSeeFace\\VSeeFace_Data\\Plugins\\x86_64\\LeapCV5.dll") failed (error c000007b).
0118:trace:loaddll:build_module Loaded L"C:\\VSeeFace\\VSeeFace_Data\\Plugins\\x86_64\\CONCRT140.dll" at 0000000104CA0000: native
0118:err:module:import_dll Loading library MSVCP140_2.dll (which is needed by L"C:\\VSeeFace\\VSeeFace_Data\\Plugins\\x86_64\\LeapCV5.dll") failed (error c000007b).
[mvk-info] Created 2 swapchain images with initial size (1280, 720) and contents scale 1.0 for screen Integriertes Retina-Display.
[mvk-error] VK_ERROR_INITIALIZATION_FAILED: Render pipeline compile failed (Error code 2):
Vertex attribute v4(4) of type int4 cannot be read using MTLAttributeFormatUInt4.

0118:trace:loaddll:build_module Loaded L"C:\\VSeeFace\\UnityPlayer.dll" at 0000000180000000: native
0118:fixme:thread:get_thread_times not implemented on this platform

0118:trace:loaddll:build_module Loaded L"C:\\windows\\system32\\mmdevapi.dll" at 0000000336850000: builtin
0118:trace:loaddll:build_module Loaded L"C:\\windows\\system32\\winecoreaudio.drv" at 00000001C92D0000: builtin
0118:fixme:coreaudio:ca_channel_layout_to_channel_mask Unhandled channel 0xffffffff
0
01b0:fixme:kernelbase:AppPolicyGetThreadInitializationType FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFA, 0000000066D6FE10
01b0:trace:loaddll:build_module Loaded L"C:\\windows\\system32\\avrt.dll" at 00000002F2930000: builtin
01b0:fixme:avrt:AvSetMmThreadCharacteristicsW (L"Audio",0000000066D6FDB8): stub
01b0:trace:loaddll:free_modref Unloaded module L"C:\\windows\\system32\\avrt.dll" : builtin
```

***If needed I could post the complete log file. ***

---

**I have installed the dlls and they are in all the folders. I have also tried the installation via Winetricks, where it displays the following message:**

```
Executing mkdir -p /Applications/Wineskin/VSeeFace.app/Contents/SharedSupport

warning: You are using a 64-bit WINEPREFIX. Note that many verbs only install 32-bit versions of packages. If you encounter problems, please retest in a clean 32-bit WINEPREFIX before reporting a bug.

Using winetricks 20220411-next - sha256sum: 846f79cac49697fd818f06a6aebf36ca408661f89b97633e9872025b33bc0e7b with wine-7.7 (WineskinCX 22.0.1) and WINEARCH=win64
Unknown arg UnityPlayer.dll
Usage: Applications/Wineskin/VSeeFace.app/Wineskin.app/Contents/Resources/winetricks \[options\] \[command|verb|path-to-verb\] ...
Executes given verbs.  Each verb installs an application or changes a setting.

Options:
\--country=CC      Set country code to CC and don't detect your IP address
\-f, --force           Don't check whether packages were already installed
\--gui             Show gui diagnostics even when driven by commandline
\--gui=OPT         Set OPT to kdialog or zenity to override GUI engine
\--isolate         Install each app or game in its own bottle (WINEPREFIX)
\--self-update     Update this application to the last version
\--update-rollback Rollback the last self update
\-k, --keep_isos       Cache isos (allows later installation without disc)
\--no-clean        Don't delete temp directories (useful during debugging)
\-q, --unattended      Don't ask any questions, just install automatically
\-r, --ddrescue        Retry hard when caching scratched discs
\-t  --torify          Run downloads under torify, if available
\--verify          Run (automated) GUI tests for verbs, if available
\-v, --verbose         Echo all commands as they are executed
\-h, --help            Display this message and exit
\-V, --version         Display version and exit

Commands:
list                  list categories
list-all              list all categories and their verbs
apps list             list verbs in category 'applications'
benchmarks list       list verbs in category 'benchmarks'
dlls list             list verbs in category 'dlls'
fonts list            list verbs in category 'fonts'
games list            list verbs in category 'games'
settings list         list verbs in category 'settings'
list-cached           list cached-and-ready-to-install verbs
list-download         list verbs which download automatically
list-manual-download  list verbs which download with some help from the user
list-installed        list already-installed verbs
arch=32|64            create wineprefix with 32 or 64 bit, this option must be
given before prefix=foobar and will not work in case of
the default wineprefix.
prefix=foobar         select WINEPREFIX=/Users/myusername/.local/share/wineprefixes/foobar
annihilate            Delete ALL DATA AND APPLICATIONS INSIDE THIS WINEPREFIX
```

Winetricks Commands Finished!!